# Applying Rules for a single product pro-grammatically

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog-rules

I have a store of around `30000` products and I want to apply rules for single product by using `SKU` of that Product. If i go and update the same via admin panel is reflecting but i would like to achieve the same pro-grammatically. I have also gone through applying rules pro-grammatically for all the products

Comment: Need to create new shopping cart / catalog rules for a product pro-grammatically or apply existing rules pro-grammatically?

Comment: @abdul i don't want to create any rule, i just want to apply an existing rule to that sku

Comment: is it shopping cart or catalog rules?

Comment: @Abdul it is Catalog Rules

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
$ruleId = <rule_Id>;
$productSku = <sku>;    
$shoppingCartPriceRule = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->load($ruleId);
$skuCondition = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule_condition_product')
                ->setType('catalogrule/rule_condition_product')
                ->setAttribute('sku')
                ->setOperator('==')
                ->setValue($sku);
try {    
   $catalogPriceRule->getConditions()->addCondition($skuCondition);
   $catalogPriceRule->save();                
   $catalogPriceRule->applyAll();     
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
  die();//remove die when in production and set the error message in session and return
}
```

I have not tested this code but this should work. Let us know if further help is needed.

Comment: @simplfsaif i want the rules applied to catalog rules, not for sales rules

Comment: sorry sorry ! I have update answer